# Extjs: Dynamic store bind to combo box- array

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm beginner to Extjs, adding an array of options for combobox in Extjs dynamically, but options in combo box appears with the 1st character of strings.
code:

```
function makeComboBox(){

var ImageCbx = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    id : cbID,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField : 'names',
    valueField: 'names',
    typeAhead : false,
    mode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    selectOnFocus : false,
    //editable : true,
    emptyText:'Select...',
    width : 400
});
function rewrite()
{
    var options = params[attach];//options=["apple", "ball", "cat"];
    var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields : ['names'],
    data : options 
    });
    var cbx = Ext.getCmp(cbID);
    cbx.bindStore(store);
}
//output: options in combo box appears with 1st char of strings
a
b
c

//Expected output:
apple
ball
cat
```

Any suggestions ? where i have done wrong

Answer (score 0):

A normal ExtJS store takes objects, not strings.

Since you use the store field "names" as the displayField, the data you want to add has to be in the format:

```
[{ names: "apple" },{names: "ball"}, {names: "cat"}]
```

which you can get with the following code:

```
data: options.map(function(option) {
    return {names: option};
})
```

You are using a "SimpleStore" which is also called ["ArrayStore"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.ArrayStore.html) since it takes arrays (not strings).

In that case you have to wrap the string into an array, so use the following code:

```
data: options.map(function(option) {
    return [ option ];
})
```

This also tells us why your store shows the first character - a string is an array, with each character being one element of the array.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the quick response..i tried with the suggested code..but now options are blank..please suggest

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I have found my error and amended the answer.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the explanation. still same output with blank, i understand the cause but i could not able to fix. In the 2nd code snippet of yours, I have also try with change of displayField as 'data' but i could not find the solution. Please suggest on the mistake

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Please make a [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com) that exhibits the problem.